# traceroute to google cloud instance

Tags: linux

When I do a trace route to our Google Cloud instance, it goes all the way to United Kingdom and times out.  It then goes to our Google Cloud instance.  It is causing our application to run slow. Any reason the routes to our Google Cloud instance is taking long time?

Answer (score 2):

> It is causing our application to run slow.

No, traceroute timeouts have *zero* bearing on application performance.

In order to diagnose this, you'll need to collect meaningful stats, CPU/Memory/IO/Network usage, HTTP-level timings, etc.. If you're not familiar with HTTP testing tools, look into your browser's devel console and also [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/), which can help diagnose which parts of your application are performing poorly.